# DoDataExchange VC++ 6.0

Tags: visual-c++

I inherited an very old application that I am in the process of updating it (I know, we should have rewrote it in VS 2008, but we purchased a company, which is how I was stuck with the relic). Using UpdateData(TRUE) to retrieve the changes made in the dialog controls, nothing is being updated. I have an edit control, with an integer variable, and an edit control with a string variable, assigned using the class wizard. Upon pressing the OK button, the UpdateData(TRUE) is executed to retrieve the new values from the disalog.

I seem to remember having a similar problem back when VS C++ 6.0 first came out, but have not used it since VS 2003 and C# became prevalent.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Bill

Comment: post the DoDateExchange method of the dialog class

Answer (score 1):

Check the DoDataExchange() method. It should have the logic for writing data to or reading it from the controls. If the programmers used the default implementastion, then there will be a DDX_... macro for each control that is being read/written. Just look at any other MFC dialogs (in your code or google) to see how the DDX commands should be written if they are missing.

Alternatively, if it's only 1 or 2 values you can easily just get the control and read it directly if you don't mind doing validation etc yourself. Get the ID of the control from the form designer and use something along the lines of:

```
CEditWnd *pWnd = GetDlgItem(ID_THECONTROL);
CString newValue = pWnd->GetWindowText();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look at the content of the `DoDataExchange` method and see what it is doing. There is not sufficient information here to tell what could be going wrong other than that.